# Memory Segments

Tags: c++, memory

I'm currently learning about dynamic memory in C++ and I've found many troubles while trying to fully comprehend and understand the memory segments within a program's memory.

So we have 4 memory segments: Stack, Heap, Data and Code.

Firstly I want to see if I got the basic of it

**- Stack:** a memory segment which is being managed like a stack
once you go into a scope, you have a limited memory allocated within that segment for that scope that shall contain info regarding that scope 
( variables, etc )

**- Heap:** a dynamic memory segment that is unlimited and when you allocate a memory in that segment it will not be deleted as you exit the scope of the code or function used and it needs to be deleted by you or a gc ( if it is unreachable anymore )

**- Code:** a memory segment containing the code that needs to be executed by the CPU

**- Data:** a memory segment containing information regarding variables ( int x - x represents memory cell 0x0FA20F )

My first question is, did I get it right? I'm really not sure....

If I did not get it right my questions are:

- what is each memory segment used for?
- In which memory segment information regarding variables, for example,
  `int x` - x represents memory cell `0x0FA20F` is located?
- When using recursion, when you call a function from within the
  function and still have code left to execute in that function, that
  code is saved in what people call a Stack, to what does that refer?,
  the regular Stack segment? if so does that mean that within the stack
  regular code lines that need to be executed in your current scope are stored?
  so what is the Code memory segment used for?

I'd love it if someone could organize the mess that is in my mind right now and explain to me what does each memory segment fully does while referring to my questions.

Comment: The data segment is for global and/or static variables. BTW, please note that in general, the whole issue of memory segments is not defined by the language standard, but rather subjected to compiler implementation (that is probably why your question was voted to be closed by 3 different users (though personally, I do not agree with that attitude, the question seems legitimate and well phrased)).

Answer (score 9):

You're close, but not quite there. You're referring to quite an old model, something akin to real-mode x86 memory. However, let's run with it and try to clear up some confusion...

First, C++ (as specified by the standard) doesn't make any reference to terms such as *stack* or *heap* when talking about the memory model. Those are specifics of the implementation. To proceed, let's assume that you're talking about a typical x86 (32- or 64-bit) PC implementation.

C++ itself defines the following [*storage durations*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration):

- **static**: Allocated when the program begins, and deallocated when the program ends. Variables with this storage duration correspond roughly to storage in the *data* segment on x86 systems.
- **automatic**: Allocated at the beginning of the enclosing code block, and deallocated at the end of the enclosing block. These are *local* variables, and will be allocated on the *stack* in x86 systems.
- **dynamic**: Allocated through `new`, deallocated through `delete`. The variable persists until deleted, and would be allocated on the *heap* in your implementation.
- **thread local**: Allocated when the thread begins and deallocated when the thread ends.

There's also a *bss* segment, for zero-initialised variables.

Each function call has its own stack frame, which includes all of the variables with automatic storage duration, as well as the arguments to the function, space for the return value, and a stored copy of the state of the calling function. When the function returns, this state is restored so that you can continue where you left off. Part of this state is the *instruction pointer*, which is a pointer to the next instruction to be executed. The instruction sequence itself is always in the *code* segment; it doesn't get copied into the stack.

This is something of a simplification, and for most uses you don't need to know anything beyond the standard definition of storage durations; the rest is an implementation detail!

[Note: Modern usage tends to think in terms of memory access permissions. Code will be loaded into memory pages which are *read-only* and *executable*, while data (including the stack) will be in *read-write* pages that are ideally marked *non-executable*. Any further distinction is somewhat meaningless, except perhaps that of stack/heap.]

Comment: Just an implementation detail (possibly Linux specific) relating to BSS/static. Objects with static storage duration will actually get distributed between data and BSS, depending if it's initialized, initialized to zero or not. In this case, uninitialized objects with static storage duration shall be zero initialized.

Comment: @borancar Yeah, that's true. I tried to steer clear of implementation details, except where needed to phrase the storage durations in terms of the memory model referenced in the question. It's hard to know where to stop when answering questions like this. Hopefully I didn't just further add to the confusion!

Answer (score 6):

> My first question is, did I get it right? I'm really not sure....

You seem to talk about segments as they were in the time of *real-mode* x86 arch. Now everything is different.

> what is each memory segment used for?

Now you should think in terms of access modes. 'Code' is the memory pages which you may 'read' and 'execute'; 'Data' = 'read' and 'write' etc.

> In which memory segment information regarding variables, for example, int x - x represents memory cell 0x0FA20F is located?

Nowhere. Named variables exist only in source files (and intermediate object code files). Actual code has only 'number' addresses.

> When using recursion, when you call a function from within the function and still have code left to execute in that function, that code is saved in what people call a Stack, to what does that refer?

'Code' is read-only and it's not to be saved anywhere, except where it resides. What is saved is local (i.e. stack) variables and return addresses. Both are saved on the stack.

Comment: I'm really sorry but I've failed to understand your explanation, Let's go again through the basics, firstly

Stack only contains variables and addresses within it? It does not contain code that needs be executed?

Let's say I have the following code:

Comment: void main(){
string s = "saxasfsdagsdgasdg";

int x  = 55;

x = x * 2;

cout << x << endl << s

x = x - 3;

cout << x

}


Now which elements would be saved where?
information regarding the variable x or s,
for example let's refer to s, s represents some memory cell, what if the data I contain in that memory cell is bigger than one byte, I need to save somewhere how many bytes is that memory cell, where is that information saved? the arithmetic operations that are left to execute, are also saved somewhere, where are these saved?

Comment: @user3687265 There's a difference between executable _file_ and actual program's _memory image_. Stack is just the specialized piece of 'data' which is allocated by OS loader in computer's memory. There's no stack in executable file at all.

Comment: @user3687265 The data size is encoded within each instruction. Thus the compiler decides which variable consists of how many bytes (and this is why data types as 'int' exist).

Comment: Okay so I'm still not quiet getting this, Let's say my program while running is using some variables, doesn't it need to know the data size? how would it be able to execute actions upon that data cell within the CPU level if it doesn't know how big it is?

Comment: @user3687265 `the arithmetic operations that are left to execute, are also saved somewhere, where are these saved?` This depends upon compiler's generated code. The code may use registers, or dedicated unvisible stack variables etc.

Comment: @user3687265 `doesn't it need to know the data size?` 'Add bytes' or 'Add double bytes' are _different_ CPU instructions.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily say everything is different, it's just our C++ model of abstraction that has become different. At least one implementation (Linux) for at least 3 archs (x86, x86_64, ARM) still refers to the segments.

Comment: ehhh, This isn't my question I guess, Let's take another example,
Class vs Structure, If I use a class, lets saying containing an int and a string, and summon an instance of the class called d, d will contain a pointer to the address of the structure in the data? however when using struct it will contain the first object of the structure, How does my program now how long is the structure?

Comment: @user3687265 Ask yourself what you actually can do with the structure? `sizeof` is just a number; address of the structure is the address of its first field; everything else works only with particular fields, not with a structure as a whole.

Answer (score 3):

Well, mostly right, we actually have 5 segments: Stack, Heap, Text (code), Data, BSS (Block start by segment - historical name).

To clarify data and the one you've missed - BSS:

1. Static and global variables which you have initialized will go to data
2. Static and global variables without initialization will go into bss and be initialized to 0

When using recursion, the program code lives in Text (code), but the local variables of the functions, some of the function arguments (depends on architecture) and the return value (depends on architecture) live on the stack. And yes, that is inside the regular stack segment.

On Linux, you can use the size command on an executable to give you a report of the sizes:

```
[root@boran ~]# size /bin/bash
text       data     bss     dec     hex filename
902580    35984   22920  961484   eabcc /bin/bash
```

When I want to start my bash interpreter, the OS will allocate the text section and copy code to it. It will allocate the data section and copy data to it, but it will allocate the size of BSS and zero it. Afterwards, each program gets a stack size and the OS dynamically gives it to you in chunks to keep up. Heap is something you manually allocate then by invoking system calls. Both heap and stack sizes can be limited. Finally, the program will get invoked by jumping to an address within the code section.